# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, radio-button

I have a list of radio buttons. When one is clicked, I want to call a function to change some text on the page. Webstorm does not show any errors in the code, and it looks fine to me, but when I click one of the radio buttons in a browser I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", specifically pointing to the last `>` in the code.

This is for a project and I desperately need to make this work! Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm happy to add more of the code if needed. Thanks!

```
<input type="radio" onclick="showPrice(<%= rs[0] %>);" 
                       name="selectedService" value="<%= rs[0][i].service_id %>" 
                       id="selectedService<%= i %>">
```

EDIT: 
Per request, here is the contents of `showPrice(object)`. `#servicesForm` is the id for the form with the radio buttons.

```
<script>
    function showPrice(services) {
        console.log("hello");
        serviceID = $('input[name=selectedService]:checked', '#servicesForm').val();
        for ( i = 0; i < services.length; i++ ) {
            if ( services[i].service_id == serviceID ) {
                checkedValue = i;
            }
        }
        price = services[checkedValue].monthly_price;
        $("servicePriceString").text(price);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: can you show the contents of your `showPrice` function?

Comment: Where does `i` come from? what are the `<%=` thingies?

Comment: `i` is from a for loop that generates the radio buttons based on how many results come back from the database. `<%=` allows me to access the data passed to the page in the request. Or variables defined in javascript between `<% %>`.

Comment: @ChadLewis but this is  `<% %>`  the problem

Comment: @sharmask No, I don't think so. The browser handles that fine and shows the expected integer values.

Comment: @ChadLewis ok...`showPrice(<%= rs[0] %>)` when browser run how is this change something like `showPrice(number )` or ``showPrice(something else )``..because i can't run this code?

Comment: @sharmask `rs` is a two-dimensional array, so `rs[0]` is the first array within `rs`.

Comment: @ChadLewis ok  `id="selectedService<%= i %>"` this `i` ..because your error  is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` its means `rs` array or something doesn't have a  your specified `identifier` .. and you got error after enter in the function or before enter the function ..?

Comment: Sorry if I'm being stupid now, but shouldn't you call your function like this: `"showPrice('<%= rs[0] %>');"` with the extra apostrophe?

Comment: @chrisv That got rid of the uncaught syntax error, but now `services` in `showPrice(services)` is undefined.

Comment: @sharmask Before getting into the function. It was never called

Comment: @ChadLewis so recheck you data fetching with proper  index identifier then try maybe there is a problem.. and my suggestion is move to some other method instead  of onClick

Comment: What's the result of using `<%= rs[0] %>` in HTML (what do you get)? How does it look? Is it all in one line, or multiple lines? Could be bad formatting. BTW Have you tried setting it manually as a variable in your JavaScript: `var services = '<%= rs[0] %>'` NB: Remember the apostrophes here also! ;)

Comment: @chrisv Thank you very much for your suggestions but I found the solution after four days of trying everything I could think of! :p

Comment: Glad you finally solved it ;) Guess you have a head ache now! :P

Comment: @chrisv You guessed correctly lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution! Many thanks to those who helped me :D. I needed to display `monthly_price` based on which radio button was selected, so I set each button's `id` attribute equal to the `monthly_price` for that specific element in `rs[0]` in the for loop. I then got the value of that attribute and set the text I wanted to change equal to that value in `showPrice()`. Below is the code.

```
<script>

    function showPrice() {
        $("#servicePriceString").text($('input[name=selectedService]:checked', '#servicesForm').attr('id'));

    }
</script>
```

.
.
.

```
<% for ( var i=0; i < rs[0].length; i++) { %>
            <label for="<%=rs[0][i].monthly_price%>">
            <div id="serviceAvailableArea">
                <input type="radio" id="<%=rs[0][i].monthly_price%>" onclick="showPrice()"
                       name="selectedService" value="<%= rs[0][i].service_id %>">
                <%= rs[0][i].service_name %> at <%= rs[0][i].speed %>Mbps
            </div>
            </label>
            <br/>

        <% }%>
```